# anonymous functions and overloaded methods in F#

Tags: f#

So, if you want to write out a line to the console in F#, you do the following:

```
System.Console.WriteLine "foo"
```

Originally I thought the following was pretty much identical, just more verbose, but actually it gives the error "A unique overload for method 'WriteLine' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point":

```
(fun line -> System.Console.WriteLine line) "foo"
```

It seems the second version is confused by the presence of overloaded WriteLine methods that take a string as well as other arguments. Is my assumption along the right lines?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not exactly.  In the first case, the function call knows that it's being applied to a string literal, so it can do overload resolution to find the string overload.

In the second case, `line` is an unsolved type variable to type inference at the point of the call to the overloaded `WriteLine` method, so it doesn't know which overload to pick, and it hasn't seen the string argument yet, as type inference is left-to-right.

Change it to

```
"foo" |> (fun line -> System.Console.WriteLine line)
```

and it will work, because the type inference variable for `line` will get unified with `string` from "foo" coming in, *before* it needs to determine the `WriteLine` call.

So they key is left-to-right type inference; in the absence of a solution to a type variable, it may not be possible to pick an overload yet.